# pcap.h no such file or directory

Tags: shared-libraries

I'm trying to install Fluxion on Kali Linux 20.2
All installed fine except Pyrit
Trying to install Pyrit on the side

```sh
python setup.py clean 
python setup.py build
```

I receive the following :

```sh
fatal error: pcap.h: No such file or directory
```

Which is weird because I have installed succesfully Libcap-dev, `apt-get install libcap-dev` returns:

```sh
libcap-dev is already the newest version (1:2.34-2).
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I got it right, I missed the p : libpcap-dev, not libcap-dev